# 2 Computers can't ping each other

Tags: networking, ping

I have 3 devices connected to a WiFi router.

1. 192.168.2.114 - Windows 10 PC
2. 192.168.2.119 - Linux Manjaro PC
3. 192.168.2.101 - Android Phone

Router has 192.168.2.1

- All devices can ping the router.
- All devices can ping the phone.
- The phone can ping all devices.
- The Windows PC can't ping the Linux PC and the Linux PC can't ping the Windows PC.

How is that possible? Firewalls are off as well.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by restarting the router.